# Variables staying null in vue.js application for shopify

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am building up a vue.js application for Shopify's JavaScript Buy SDK, but i am having problems with one variable not being updated.

Basically the `shopClient` variable is updated, but the `shopCart` stays null for some reason.

```
var vueApp = new Vue({
    el: '#shopify-app',
    created: function() {
        this.setupShopAndCart();
    },
    data: {
        shopCart: null,
        shopClient: null,
    },
    methods: {
        setupShopAndCart: function() {
            this.shopClient = ShopifyBuy.buildClient({
                apiKey: 'xxx',
                domain: 'xxx.myshopify.com',
                appId: '6'
            });
            if(localStorage.getItem('lastCartId')) {
              this.shopClient.fetchCart(localStorage.getItem('lastCartId')).then(function(remoteCart) {
                this.shopCart = remoteCart;
                cartLineItemCount = this.shopCart.lineItems.length;
                console.log(this.shopCart.checkoutUrl);
                console.log("fetching");
              });
            } else {
              this.shopClient.createCart().then(function (newCart) {
                this.shopCart = newCart;
                localStorage.setItem('lastCartId', this.shopCart.id);
                cartLineItemCount = 0;
                console.log(this.shopCart.checkoutUrl);
                console.log("failing");
              });
            }
        }, //setupShop end
    }
});
```

Comment: How do you know `shopCart` is null? I mean, how you check it?

Comment: It seems like `ShopifyBuy` is an external library. You should not place it in this way. Because Vue will watch for changes on it. Just store it with `_` at the start. I mean `this._shopClient` much better

Comment: @probil, yes i checked it through the VUE debugger in Chrome. Its always null.

Comment: ok. @JavaCake, can you add console.log of `newCart` and `remoteCart` in each `then()`?

Comment: None of them are null.. Is there a problem with the syncing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem with scoping. `this` in the promise isn't the vue instance.

try this

```
var vueApp = new Vue({
    el: '#shopify-app',
    created: function() {
        this.setupShopAndCart();
    },
    data: {
        shopCart: null,
        shopClient: null,
    },
    methods: {
        setupShopAndCart: function() {
            var self = this;
            this.shopClient = ShopifyBuy.buildClient(
                {
                    apiKey: 'xxx',
                    domain: 'xxx.myshopify.com',
                    appId: '6'
                }
            );
            if(localStorage.getItem('lastCartId')) {
                this.shopClient.fetchCart(localStorage.getItem('lastCartId')).then(
                    function(remoteCart) {
                        self.shopCart = remoteCart;
                        cartLineItemCount = self.shopCart.lineItems.length;
                        console.log(self.shopCart.checkoutUrl);
                        console.log("fetching");
                    }
                );
            } else {
                this.shopClient.createCart().then(
                    function (newCart) {
                        self.shopCart = newCart;
                        localStorage.setItem('lastCartId', self.shopCart.id);
                        cartLineItemCount = 0;
                        console.log(self.shopCart.checkoutUrl);
                        console.log("failing");
                    }
                );
            }
        }, //setupShop end
    }
});
```

That stores the local vue instance in the self variable that is accessable to the promises allowing you to set the shopCart variable.

EDIT: As indicated lambda functions are correct if using ES2015 or newer

```
var vueApp = new Vue({
    el: '#shopify-app',
    created: function() {
        this.setupShopAndCart();
    },
    data: {
        shopCart: null,
        shopClient: null,
    },
    methods: {
        setupShopAndCart: function() {
            this.shopClient = ShopifyBuy.buildClient(
                {
                    apiKey: 'xxx',
                    domain: 'xxx.myshopify.com',
                    appId: '6'
                }
            );
            if(localStorage.getItem('lastCartId')) {
                this.shopClient.fetchCart(localStorage.getItem('lastCartId')).then(
                    (remoteCart) => {
                        this.shopCart = remoteCart;
                        cartLineItemCount = this.shopCart.lineItems.length;
                        console.log(this.shopCart.checkoutUrl);
                        console.log("fetching");
                    }
                );
            } else {
                this.shopClient.createCart().then(
                    (newCart) => {
                        this.shopCart = newCart;
                        localStorage.setItem('lastCartId', this.shopCart.id);
                        cartLineItemCount = 0;
                        console.log(this.shopCart.checkoutUrl);
                        console.log("failing");
                    }
                );
            }
        }, //setupShop end
    }
});
```

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. But you can enhance it by using **arrow function expression**, instead of storing `this` in a local variable.

Comment: Detailed discussion on the arrow function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6

Comment: I agree, if they are using ES 2015 or newer lamda functions are the better option for continuing scope.