# Is there a difference from these 2 functions?

Tags: javascript

I have downloaded an open source js code where the developer often create new function in this way:

```
var log = msg => div.innerHTML += "<br>" + msg;
```

So, is there a difference with this below ?

```
function log(msg){
   div.innerHTML += "<br>" + msg;
}
```

Comment: There are some differences between arrow functions and `function foo() {}` functions. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some differences between arrow functions and `function foo() {}` functions. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions.

A few I can think of off the top of my head:

- `function foo() {}` function *definitions* are hoisted, which means you can invoke such a function anywhere in the scope that contains its definition. This is not the case for variables containing functions, for which only the *declarations* are hoisted
- Arrow functions bind `this` lexically, which in simple words means that they do not introduce their own `this` variable. Instead, they simply close over the nearest `this` variable from an enclosing scope
- Arrow functions do not have the [`arguments` local variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) available for use within the body

All that said, the two functions you have shown should behave identically in most cases, given the caveats mentioned above.