# How to access this. in OnSucess() or OnFailure()

Tags: angular, observable

How do I get the this.ID in the OnSuccess and in OnFailure?

I'm trying to import a dictionary into my angular project using pagemethods.

```
ID:number = 1;

ngAfterViewInit() {
     window['PageMethods'].getCustomAction(this.OnSuccess, this.OnFailure);
}

OnSuccess(succes:any) 
{
    if(1 == this.ID)
    {
         //Code
    }
}

OnFailure(error:any) 
{

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap the callback methods in a lambda to preserve the `this` context:

```ts
window['PageMethods'].getCustomAction(
    (success: any) => this.OnSuccess(success), 
    (error: any) => this.OnFailure(error)
);
```

Then you can use your class members in `OnSuccess` and `OnFailure`.

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you.

I have no idea how I should have learned this, any advice how to learn these things?

Comment: Well, the `this` context in JS is really a magic thing. So a rule of thumb is to always use lambdas (`() => ...`) instead of inline functions, because they automatically bind to the context in which they have been defined and just don't pass functions only, like you did in your question. Then you should be fine :D

Comment: A gotcha with lambdas is though, that if you want to add more lines to be executed, you have to explicitly return something, if it's needed, while lambdas without the curly braces body implicitly return the value, they are called with. [More on this here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6/23045200#23045200)

Comment: Btw you don't need to add `any` in the lambda heading since it's implicitly of type `any` if not stated otherwise.

Comment: removing the :any results in [ts] parameter 'error' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Comment: Uh, it's a mere warning, iirc - but if that's the style guide for TypeScript, I'll add it. (following Angular 2 Dart for too long now, I guess)