# Ionic2 using NavController.setRoot in resolved Promise

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using the JS Library with Parse Server and having issues navigating to another page on successful login.

Using this function `this.navCtrl.setRoot(TemplatesPage);` doesn't do anything in my app.

My full code is below and I can confirm in the console that the success function is being called and I have also tried `pop` before I tried `setRoot`.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, AlertController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { User } from '../../models/user-model';
import { SignupPage } from '../signup/signup';
import { TemplatesPage } from '../templates/templates';
import Parse from 'parse';

@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {

  user : User = {
    username : '',
    password: ''
  }

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {

  }

  login() {

    Parse.User.logIn(this.user.username, this.user.password).then(function(user) {

      console.log('Success' + user);

      this.navCtrl.setRoot(TemplatesPage);

    }, function(err) {

      this.alertCtrl
       .create({title: "Error", message: err.text(), buttons: [{
         text: 'OK',
       }]})
       .present();

    })
  }

  goToTemplatePage() {
    this.navCtrl.push(TemplatesPage);
  }

  gotToSignup() {
    this.navCtrl.push(SignupPage);
  }

}
```

[image: Console showing success and no error]

Comment: are you getting anything in the console?

Comment: @SurajRao I get a successful XHR called to my server and the console.log() from the success function.

Comment: any errors for the setRoot?

Comment: No, added an image to show my console.

Comment: does calling goToTemplatePage work?

Comment: Yep, hence having to resort to SO in my desperate need.

Comment: cant be sure..but it may have something to do with value f 'this'..try using arrow function instead of function in then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The this used inside the function(user) will not refer loginPage. It refers to your function. Arrow functions behave differently, they fix the problem with `this`. The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6) expalins when to use arrow functions.
Try then and catch with arrow functions:

```
 Parse.User.logIn(this.user.username, this.user.password).then((user)=> {

      console.log('Success' + user);

      this.navCtrl.setRoot(TemplatesPage);

    }).catch((err)=> {

      this.alertCtrl
       .create({title: "Error", message: err.text(), buttons: [{
         text: 'OK',
       }]})
       .present();

    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone may know why, however thanks to the commenters I replaced `.then` with `=>` and it works.

Completed function below:

```
Parse.User.logIn(this.user.username, this.user.password).then(user => {
  console.log('Success' + user);
  this.navCtrl.setRoot(TemplatesPage);

}, err => {
  console.log('error called')
  this.alertCtrl
   .create({title: "Error", message: err.text(), buttons: [{
     text: 'OK',
   }]})
   .present();
})
```

Comment: The reason is because of the context. When using `user => { //... }` you still can access to the component properties and thus, to `this.navCtrl...` but if you don't, the component properties are not available there because `this` points to something different than the component.