# What does Javascript Arrow function with object as parameter mean?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I was learning ReactJS here:
https://egghead.io/lessons/react-dynamically-generated-components and came across this code snippet:

```
componentWillMount(){
    fetch( 'http://swapi.co/api/people/?format=json')
        .then( response => response.json() )
        .then( ({results: items}) => this.setState({items}) )
}
```

What does the `({results: items})` part of the arrow function mean?

I've seen arrow function

- with no parameter `()=>console.log('hi')`
- without parenthesis `word=>console.log(word)`
- and with multiple parameter seperated by comma `(one, two)=>console.log(one)`

But never an object literal in this way.

Also, why does `this.setState({items})` need curly braces around `items`? What does it all mean?

Comment: may be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6

Comment: the duplicate doesn't explain `{results: items}` does it?

Comment: @JaromandaX i am not flagging this as exact duplicate, i am just telling to have a look at this also.

Comment: I was referring to the link in the **marked as duplicate** :p

Comment: oh i thought u are saying this to me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
this.setState({items})
```

is ES6 shorthand for

```
this.setState({items: items})
```

and

```
({results: items})
```

basically accepts an object as a parameter with the property named results, and in the function body this is mapped to items

run trhough a transpiler, e.g. [babel try it out repl page](http://babeljs.io/repl/) your code

```
fetch( 'http://swapi.co/api/people/?format=json')
    .then( response => response.json() )
    .then( ({results: items}) => this.setState({items}) )
```

becomes

```
var _this = this;

fetch('http://swapi.co/api/people/?format=json')
.then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
})
.then(function (_ref) {
    var items = _ref.results;
    return _this.setState({ items: items });
});
```

I would recommend keeping a link to that babel page - if any ES6 code confuses you, paste it there to see what the ES5 version is :p that's my cheat

Comment: I like your cheat :P