# Angular2 + Typescript + FileReader.onLoad = property does not exist

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filereader

I am using the **FileReader Interface** and it’s asynchronous method **readAsText()** to read a local text file, 
After that when the **onload event** is called, I try to read my file, my source code is something like the following:

```
export class ReadFileComponent {
   text: string;

   readFile(): void {
     let reader=new FileReader();
     reader.onload = function(e) {
        this.text=reader.result;
     }
     reader.readAsText(file);   
   }
}
```

compilation is failed because Property **"text"** does not exist on type **"FileReader"**

I think this is due to the EventListener interface does not accept objects ,

did someone please solve this kind of issue?

thanks guys,

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If you want to use `this` inside the callback, use an arrow function, otherwise it won't work

```
reader.onload = (e) => {
    this.text=reader.result;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: No it works fine with console.log(reader.result), the problem is with "this" means currentTarget property is of type EventTarget and not type of class ReadFileComponent

Comment: That's why you need to use `()=>` instead of `function ()`. Arrow functions ensure `this` within the callback keeps pointing at the current class.

Comment: right.. maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6) will clarify it

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that the ‘ reader.onload’ part does not work, in production [after ng build — prod].

The reason for this, is that the non Angular version is:

reader.onload = function(evt) {
}

Because this does NOT use an arrow function, the parent context is not passed in. In Angular we need access to the parent context, hence the use of arrow functions.

What actually happens, using an arrow function, is that the entire ‘onload’ function is passed to ‘reader.result’.

Comment: @CharlesRobertson not sure what you mean. My answer uses arrow function

Comment: Yes. I realise this, but what I meant, is that the Vanilla JS version works partly because it uses a non arrow function. But I also found out that the other reason it fails in Angular is because there is a bug in zone.js. A temporary fix for this can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45542462/angular-4-x-cordova-filereader-fails-silently-white-screen-of-death/45542463?noredirect=1#comment88157606_45542463

Comment: let FileReader: new() => FileReader = ((window as any).FileReader as any).__zone_symbol__OriginalDelegate;
let reader = new FileReader();

This allows the event to be passed in to 'onload' correctly, which in turn, allows us to use 'event.target.result'

Answer (score 4):

You are using a regular javascript function here:

```
 reader.onload = function(e) {
        this.text=reader.result;
     }
```

The `this` belongs to the function not your class.

Use arrow function

```
reader.onload = (e)=> {
            this.text=reader.result;
         }
```

Or

```
self = this;
 reader.onload = function(e) {
        self.text=reader.result;
     }
```