# Angular 4.x + Cordova : FileReader fails silently (white screen of death)

Tags: angular, cordova, filereader, zone.js

I have an Angular 4.3 + Cordova application that used to work very well. But now, I get a blank screen on app start-up, and nothing happens any more.

After digging a while I realized where it comes from :

my home page is protected by a `CanActivate` guard that will check some file-system-persisted preferences and redirect the user to another page if this is the first run or if a required preference is missing, to fill-in the required properties.

So the launch of the app depends on my `CanActivate` guard that depends on a `PreferenceService` that itself depends on a `FileSystemService` that I implemented myself. The problem is that when I try to read the file where user's preferences are stored, not a single callback is fired, nothing happen, **not even an error**.

this is the part of my `FileSystemService` that fails without any error :

```js
read(file: FileEntry, mode: "text" | "arrayBuffer" | "binaryString" | "dataURL" = "text"): Observable<ProgressEvent> {
    return this.cdv.ready.flatMap(() => {
        return Observable.create(observer => {
            file.file(file => {
                let reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onerror = (evt: ErrorEvent) => {
                    this.zone.run(() => observer.error(evt)); //never triggered
                };
                reader.onload = (evt: ProgressEvent) => {
                    this.zone.run(() => observer.next(evt)); //never trigerred
                };
                switch (mode) {
                    case "text":
                        reader.readAsText(file);
                        break;
                    case "arrayBuffer":
                        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
                        break;
                    case "binaryString":
                        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
                        break;
                    case "dataURL":
                        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                        break;
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Why does this even happen and how can I deal with that so my callbacks get triggered ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**EDIT**

As stated long ago, I openned an issue on zone.js repository and zone.js owner quickly patched the code. You can avoid the pain of using my dirty hack just by importing `zone.js/zone-patch-cordova` inside your polyfills.

**Original answer**

While debugging this code I realized that the `FileReader` constructor was patched by both cordova and zone.js. From what I understood regarding zone.js patching is that it changes every "onProperty" (`onload`,`onloadend`,`onerror`) to its `addEventListener(...)` counterPart.

> #### Module Name:
>
> on_property
>
> #### Behavior with zone.js :
>
> `target.onProp` will become zone aware `target.addEventListener(prop)`

[source](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/master/MODULE.md)

But cordova does not use the `dispatchEvent(...)` API to notify listeners operation has ended.

One solution might be to deactivate `onProperty` module from zone.js but **it might break angular's behavior**.

So this is how I coped with the situation :

```js
read(file: FileEntry, mode: "text" | "arrayBuffer" | "binaryString" | "dataURL" = "text"): Observable<ProgressEvent> {
    return this.cdv.ready.flatMap(() => {
        return Observable.create(observer => {
            file.file(file => {
                let FileReader: new() => FileReader = ((window as any).FileReader as any).__zone_symbol__OriginalDelegate
                let reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onerror = (evt: ErrorEvent) => {
                    this.zone.run(() => observer.error(evt)); //never triggered
                };
                reader.onload = (evt: ProgressEvent) => {
                    this.zone.run(() => observer.next(evt)); //never trigerred
                };
                switch (mode) {
                    case "text":
                        reader.readAsText(file);
                        break;
                    case "arrayBuffer":
                        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
                        break;
                    case "binaryString":
                        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
                        break;
                    case "dataURL":
                        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                        break;
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

The secret here is that zone.js keeps the original constructor in the `__zone_symbol__OriginalDelegate` property, so calling this will actually call Cordova's `FileReader` directly **without zone.js patch**.

This solution being a dirty hack,I have [openned an issue on zone's repository](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/868)

#### Edit :

Had the same problem with `FileWriter` (it internally calls a `FileReader`) so I wrote this little shim :

```js
function noZonePatch(cb: () => void) {
    const orig = FileReader;
    const unpatched = ((window as any).FileReader as any).__zone_symbol__OriginalDelegate;
    (window as any).FileReader = unpatched;
    cb();
    (window as any).FileReader = orig;
}
```

then wrapped my calls to read/write operations :

```js
write(file: FileEntry, content: Blob) {
    return this.cdv.ready.flatMap(() => {
        return Observable.create((out: Observer<ProgressEvent>) => {
            file.createWriter((writer) => {
                noZonePatch(() => {
                    writer.onwrite = (evt: ProgressEvent) => {
                        this.zone.run(() => {
                            out.next(evt);
                            out.complete();
                        });
                    };
                    writer.onerror = (evt) => {
                        this.zone.run(() => out.error(evt));
                    };
                    writer.write(content); // this is where FileReader is called internally
                })
            }, err => out.error(err));
        });
    });
}

read(file: FileEntry, mode: ReadMode = "text"): Observable<ProgressEvent> {
    return this.cdv.ready.switchMap(() => Observable.create((observer: Observer<ProgressEvent>) => {
        file.file(file => {
            noZonePatch(() => {
                let reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onerror = (evt: ErrorEvent) => {
                    this.zone.run(() => observer.error(evt));
                };
                reader.onload = (evt: ProgressEvent) => {
                    this.zone.run(() => observer.next(evt));
                };
                switch (mode) {
                    case "text":
                        reader.readAsText(file);
                        break;
                    case "arrayBuffer":
                        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
                        break;
                    case "binaryString":
                        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
                        break;
                    case "dataURL":
                        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                        break;
                }
            });
        });
    }));
}
```

Comment: You are a genius. I have spent the best part of 3 days, trying to debug this problem. I have looked at, at least 20 different solutions, that all fail. I am using Angular 5, and when I build my app, using 'ng build --prod', my 'FileReader' routine fails, because the file is passed in to 'onload' rather than the event [event.target & event.target.result]. Your one line of shining brilliance fixed this. I am not entirely sure why, but the event and all its properties are now correctly passed into 'onload' and I suspect this works for all FileReader's other events. Thank you so much...

Comment: Please check the issue I opened on zonejs's repo, they added a patch, so upgrading zone and adding the patch may fix this without my dirty hack.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, but I am using Angular, so I am not sure whether a patch is the solution, because I thought Angular has zones baked in. I may have to upgrade to Angular 6, which is a little scary!

Answer (score 2):

Something late to the party but I had to fix an Ionic3/Angular4 project with this exact problem and I found that [the answer from @n00dl3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45542463/1255819) was on point *but* there is something of a race condition when an `FileReader` instance is created in a global service. Because sometimes zone did not patched yet the `FileReader` `window` object so no `__zone_symbol__OriginalDelegate` is found.

So what I did to always get the correct class is a little factory function that returns a `FileReader` instance:

```js
function HackFileReader(): FileReader {
  const preZoneFileReader = ((window as any).FileReader as any).__zone_symbol__OriginalDelegate;
  if (preZoneFileReader) {
    console.log('%cHackFileReader: preZoneFileReader found creating new instance', 'font-size:3em; color: red');
    return new preZoneFileReader();
  } else {
    console.log('%cHackFileReader: NO preZoneFileReader was found, returning regular File Reader', 'font-size:3em; color: red');
    return new FileReader();
  }
}
```

and to use it just do :

```js
const reader = HackFileReader();
```

I hope it helps somebody

Comment: You should not use that hack anymore, as the ZoneJS team has published a patch. I'l add that detail to my answer

Comment: @n00dl3 when the codebase is old and you are not allow to update your dependencies, yes you need it :(

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ionic/cordova, there is no need for the HackFileReader solution from @disante (which I actually used)

Two things you need to do, first off is make sure you have the most current zone.js.

```
npm install --save zone.js@latest
```

Second you need to ensure that your `index.html` adds `cordova.js` **AFTER** `build/polyfills.js`