# ES6 classes and knockout foreach

Tags: knockout.js, ecmascript-6

I am having issues with the binding context using ES6 classes.

here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mbr4mjtp/) to explain.

when i declare a click function on the class like

```
class viewModel {
    constructor() {
        this.data = ko.observableArray([{ firstName: "phil" }, { firstName: "person" }]);
        this.selectedPerson = ko.observable("none selected");
    }
    selectUser(data){
        console.log(this);
        this.selectedPerson(data.firstName);
    }
}
```

I have to provide a binding in the markup like so: `<div data-bind="text: firstName, click: $parent.selectUser.bind($parent)">`

but when i declare the click in the constructor I don't have to provide the context.

anybody know why?

Comment: I suggest using https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/. WIth this u can write a method as an arrow function

Answer (score 1):

Knockout's event binding (which `click` uses under the hood) does three things:

- Pass the current binding context's `$data`,
- Pass the event
- `apply` the event listener bound to the current `$data`

([Source](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/event.js#L32))

This means that when you tap on a user, this is what happens:

```
viewModelInstance.selectUser.apply(user, [user, event]);
```

If you want to refer to `this` in your handler, it's important to know the differences between arrow functions, prototype methods and "unbound" property functions:

```
this.doSomething = function () { /* ... */ };
this.doSomething = () => { /* ... */ };

MyClass.prototype.doSomething = function() { /* ... */ };
```

When you write:

```
this.selectUser = (data) => { /* ... */ };
```

You essentially do:

```
this.selectUser = function(data) { /* ... */ }.bind(this);
```

This means the `viewModel` instance is "fixed"/bound to the method. Defining it outside the constructor makes it a prototype method that can be bound to any `this` context by other code.

Search for "es6 arrow functions" and `this` to find some more answers on how this works. For example: [When should I use Arrow functions in ECMAScript 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6)

Comment: so to avoid having to call a .bind($parent/$/root) i can declare it in the constructor to make "this" bind correctly ? i though we want to avoid logic in the constructor or does that only apply to typed languages ?

Comment: Defining it in the constructor has its downsides (like: every instance redefines the method) but it will work. Alternatively, you could include a reference to the selection model in each user, and make them have their own `select` method (my personal preference). A third option would be to use a ["postbox pattern"](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox) to communicate between models. (seems like overkill for this straight forward example)

Comment: i like the second one too(if we are on the same page so https://jsfiddle.net/mbr4mjtp/1/ for ref) but how would this work with dynamic data from a server? we would need to loop over each and add a select function. or use the mapping util. or am i totally missing the mark ?

Comment: Not missing the mark; that was exactly what I meant. If you're working with plain objects from the server, I'd advice you to make a view model with a constructor that handles both the raw data and the selection logic. For example: https://jsfiddle.net/u8wngza3/ Another tip: you could put the "name extraction logic" in a computed, which would allow you to just pass the observable that stores the selection along instead of a setter function: https://jsfiddle.net/jwupjy0m/