# Is it possible to make TS throw errors if I use "function" kw?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am translating a huge AMD JS project to TypeScript and I have noticed I have problems with the following things:

- keyword `function` introduces a lot of problems because of "this" scope. I always replace all `functions` with arrow style functions
- class methods - if a pointer to a method is sent as a parameter to another function and then called - it is also problematic, so I replace those with arrow functions as well.

I mean, when I do it - there is no problem whatsoever. But my issue is that sometimes I forget to do it and TS never shows me any error, because as a matter of fact it's not a error. So is it possible to make TS show me a warning in those cases?

Comment: Probably not. Functions are a part of the language and there's no reason for the compiler to complain about that.  Also, using arrow functions isn't always a good idea, especially in classes if you intend to override methods

Comment: are you using tslint?

Comment: @NitzanTomer, I must emphasize that I recognize all the problems that I may encounter, however I'd like to be able to do it now, at least until I translated the entire project and made sure everything works as it worked before translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution exists if you are using [`tslint`](https://github.com/palantir/tslint).

You can add the following rule to `tslint.json`:

```
"only-arrow-functions": [true, "allow-declarations", "allow-named-functions"]
```

Link:[docs](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/only-arrow-functions/)

Also as @NitzanTomer suggests [arrow functions are ideal for only certain cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6)