# what's the difference between function(){} and ()=>{} in typescript

Tags: typescript, closures

```
    class Demo{
       varA;
       method=function(){
            alert(this.varA)
             }
    }
```

this.varA not working above, varA is not accessible.

```
class Demo{
           varA;
           method= ()=>{
                    alert(this.varA)
                  }
        }
```

But, this worked. I wonder why?what's the difference between function(){} and ()=>{} in typescript.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6

Comment: this is not really confined to typescript. It is the same as javascript es6