# How do you create a named async arrow function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrow-functions, ecmascript-2017

Currently, I have this code:

```
async function getConnection(){
    // logic here...
}
```

To make it consistent with the rest of my codebase, I want to change it to an arrow function. I've tried `async getConnection () => { ... }` but that didn't seem to work. What would be the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrow functions have no name, but you can assign them to a variable like this:

```
const normalFunc = () => { ... };
const asyncFunc  = async () => { ... };
```

---

Do note, however, that arrow functions are not just shorter notation for regular functions, as there are some subtle differences to be aware of ([see this article for details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)). However, if you understand these differences and they don't affect your code, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Arrow functions can't have a name

```
const getConnection = async () => {}
```

But simple replace of all functions to arrow functions is simply stupid and in might be error-prone. [Learn all differences](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html) before doing so.

Comment: Main one being async arrow functions don't carry over context from a construction, `this` refers to `Window`.

Comment: @Crowes I think to be more clear, `this` will refer to the `this` of whatever function or object the arrow function was declared in. I'm assuming a const would be declared on the global scope so you are correct

Comment: @BrettReinhard Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 1):

An arrow function can't be declared with a name, but can be assigned.

**Try :**

```
var getConnection = async () => {
  return 'It works';
}

getConnection().then(message => console.log(message))
```

Hope this helps