# ionic 3 - undefined variable in Ionic3 page

Tags: ionic3

I have 2 questions regarding ionic 3.

1. In my ionic3 page I declare a variable called '**test**' whict cannot be access in **actionOnClick** function . Does anyone know way? What should I do so that 'test' in accessible anywere in FUNCTION_TEST function?
2. Is there a way to make possible the variables exchange between HomePage and FUNCTION_TEST?

Bellow is my ionic3 code.

```
import { Component,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Content} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  @ViewChild(Content) content:Content;
  test:string="text 1";

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  ionViewDidEnter(){
     this.FUNCTION_TEST();
  }

  FUNCTION_TEST(){
     var x=1;

     function actionOnClick(){
         alert("text="+this.test);  
     }

  }
}
```

Is it possible that my problem have to do with javascript and not with ionic?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your first question, you are trying to access a global variable inside a local enviroment (actionOnClick). To resolve this you should make your function like this, but take in mind it will not be accesible from outside (HTML page for example):

```
FUNCTION_TEST(){
     var x=1;

     let actionOnClick = () => {
         alert("text="+this.test);  
     }

  }
```

This will let you acces this.test from there.

---

Regarding your second question, I don't understand it, if you want to access actionOnClick() from your HomePage you will need to declare it as another function of the class like this:

```
FUNCTION_TEST(){
     var x=1;

  }

actionOnClick(){
         alert("text="+this.test);  
     }
```

And then call it like this for example:

```
<button ion-button block (click)="actionOnClick()">Click Me</button>
```

Hope this helps you.