# Difference between arrow function and bind()

Tags: javascript, typescript, arrow-functions

I am little confused about while object missing the reference(context).

In TypeScript (shown here with some dummy parameters for explanatory reasons):

**Fat Arrow**

```
var x = new SomeClass();    
someCallback(function(a){x.doSomething(a)});// some time this x object may 
missing the    reference (context) of x object

someCallback(a => x.doSomething(a));// if we using arrow function, then how 
it manage stabling the object context? which is doing same below bind()code.
```

bind() : **Functions created from function.bind() always preserve 'this'**

```
var x = new SomeClass();
window.setTimeout(x.someMethod.bind(x), 100);//bind will be also manage 
the x context(reference).
```

**Question:**

- What are the performance and differences between them?
- when to use `bind()` and `arrow(a=>a...)` function?

Comment: How is this related to angular ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6

Comment: This is what you need , simple googling helps http://2ality.com/2016/02/arrow-functions-vs-bind.html

Comment: not directly targeting your question, but worth reading in this context (pun intended) [How does the 'this' keyword work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70973212/334451 – I'm currently thinking the behavior differences are `bind()` has better runtime performance but it cannot react to changes in objects. In the example in this question, the version with `bind()` doesn't react to modifying `x.someMethod` after already setting the timeout. I think the performance difference mostly comes from this difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binding vs Arrow-function (in JavaScript, or for react onClick)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50375440/binding-vs-arrow-function-in-javascript-or-for-react-onclick)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the examples you give there is no difference between using `function` and using `=>`. That is because you don't reference `this` inside the callback function.

However, if your callback uses `this` the typescript compiler will convert the call to use `_this` inside the `=>` callbacks but not inside the `function` callbacks and creates a local `var _this = this`.

So for this typescript:

```
class SomeClass {
  x: any;
  foo() {

    someCallback(function(a:number){this.x.doSomething(a)});// some time may missing the reference (context) of x object

    someCallback((a:number) => this.x.doSomething(a));
  }
}
function someCallback(foo: any) {};
```

You get this javascript:

```
var SomeClass = (function () {
    function SomeClass() {
    }
    SomeClass.prototype.foo = function () {
        var _this = this;
        someCallback(function (a) { this.x.doSomething(a); }); // some time may missing the reference (context) of x object
        someCallback(function (a) { return _this.x.doSomething(a); });
    };
    return SomeClass;
}());
function someCallback(foo) { }
;
```

Answer (score 0):

`bind()` does not create an anonymous function, whereas `=>` does. (This may or may not matter to you.)

`=>` creates lexical bindings for `this` and all arguments. Wheras `bind()` only creates a lexical binding for `this`.