# angular 2 function calling inside an http post function

Tags: angular

I have a http post function.

```
login(){

    var data = {
      email : this.name,
      password : this.pass,
      appId : this.appId
    };
    console.log(data);

    this.http.post(SERVER_URL+"/templatesAuth/authenticateForApp",data)
      .subscribe(function(res){

         let requestParams = {
            "token": res.token,
            "email": data.email,
            "name": res.user.name,
            "phone": res.user.phone,
            "streetNumber": res.user.streetNumber,
            "streetName": res.user.streetName,
            "country": res.user.country,
            "city": res.user.city,
            "zip": res.user.zip,
            "type": 'internal',
            "appId":res.user.appId,
            "registeredUser": res.user.sub
          };


        },
        function(err){
          alert('login failed');
        })


  }
```

inside the `function(req){ }` I cannot write or use calls like `examplearray.push();` 
im always having an error **Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**

when I use Local storage functions like.

```
this.localStorageService.set('test'+this.appId,(requestParams));
```

error : **Cannot read property 'set' of undefined**

but I can use them out side of the `function(req){ }`. couldn't figure-out the problem

is there any way to get the requestParams outside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very common issue of scoping :

Just change the line

```
.subscribe(function(res){
```

to

```
.subscribe((res) => {
```

---

Another way of doing is :

```
.subscribe(function(res){ ... }).bind(this)
```

---

Great article to read : https://toddmotto.com/es6-arrow-functions-syntaxes-and-lexical-scoping/
and check  this answer for : [Difference between arrow function and bind()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585785/difference-between-arrow-function-and-bind/46585937)

Comment: @DilakshanSooriyanathan, Glad to here that , will you please also accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You should use arrow function .When using arrow functions,property is not overwritten 
change it as,

```
.subscribe((res) => {
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
this.http.post(SERVER_URL+"/templatesAuth/authenticateForApp",data)
  .subscribe((res) => {

     let requestParams = {
        "token": res.token,
        "email": data.email,
        "name": res.user.name,
        "phone": res.user.phone,
        "streetNumber": res.user.streetNumber,
        "streetName": res.user.streetName,
        "country": res.user.country,
        "city": res.user.city,
        "zip": res.user.zip,
        "type": 'internal',
        "appId":res.user.appId,
        "registeredUser": res.user.sub
      };


    },
    function(err){
      alert('login failed');
    })
}
```