# unable to get component variable value in angular 2 in frontend

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

Am unable to display mapLoc value in front end... any help?

Here is my component.ts file

```
export class mycomponent{

 mapLoc:any;

 constructor(){...}

openImageModal(lat,lng){
 this.mapLoc = '';
 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var geocoder = geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    if (results[1]) {
                        console.log(results[1].formatted_address); //able to console
                        this.mapLoc = results[1].formatted_address;
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

this is mycomponent.html file

```
<ngui-map zoom="{{zoom}}" center="{{lat}}, {{lng}}" (mapReady$)="onMapReady($event,lat,lng)" (mapClick)="onMapClick($event)" (idle)="onIdle($event)">
                <marker *ngFor="let pos of position" [position]="[pos.lat, pos.lng]" draggable="true" (initialized$)="onMarkerInit($event)"></marker>
                    <info-window id="iw">
                        <div *ngIf="marker.display">
                        {{mapLoc}}
                        </div>
                    </info-window>
            </ngui-map>
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `this` can be different inside the callback *(To check this, try `console.log("this", this)` inside the callback.)*. Try using a [big arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead to keep reference to your component.

```
    geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, (results, status) => {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[1]) {
                    this.mapLoc = results[1].formatted_address;
                }
            }
        });
```

or cache a reference and use it in the old way:

```
    let component = this;
    geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[1]) {
                    console.log(results[1].formatted_address); //able to console
                    component.mapLoc = results[1].formatted_address;
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

That is very common issue of scoping :

Just change :

```
geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
```

to

```
geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, (results, status) => {
```

OR

```
geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) { ... }).bind(this)
```

For More Detail Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47278161/2349407

Comment: @Esco, will you please accept and upvote the answer?

Comment: I already tried doing that. I cannot upvote as my points are less than the min required points. However, stackoverflow says it'll be recorded.