# Get current (this) with arrow function

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get the "old" this, like you would get with function()?

```
addEventListener("click", () => { console.log(this) }) // {}

addEventListener("click", function() => { console.log(this) }) // EventEmitter /.../
```

Comment: Read [How to Ask A Good Question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I think this question would be way easier to read if you presented the expected behaviour first and the actual afterwards. Currently it's the other way around.

Comment: [When should I use Arrow functions in ECMAScript 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6)

Answer (score 1):

Your question was unclear to me.

If you want the current clicked element, use the property `currentTarget` on your event :

```
addEventListener("click", (e) => { console.log(e.currentTarget) })
```

If you want the previous `this`, just store it previously :

```
var that = this;
addEventListener("click", () => { console.log(that) })
```

Comment: I believe this is the opposite of what @Glutch was asking.

Comment: As I understand it, he wants the `this` previous to his event. Isn't that the case?

Comment: No, he wants the "old" `this` functionality, as provided by `function() {}` but in an arrow function.

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I'll post another solution then.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to make arrow function behave like this - preserving the current `this` is what it was designed for.

Your best solution is to just use `function() {}` when you need `this` to be provided to you.

Answer (score 1):

Arrow functions in JavaScript do not create a new context and therefore no "new" or "old" `this`. They are using whatever is available in their scope of definition.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions:

> An arrow function does not have its own `this`; the `this` value of the enclosing execution context is used.

This behaviour is exactly the same as with lambda functions in other languages.