# Ionic 3 array and undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

I've got a serious problem with this function in Ionic, I'm trying to fix this for several days but with no success.
I'm developing an app "like Instagram". I upload the photo on Firebase and also the link to download it, but when I try to display the photos in the home via links I receive only `Cannot read property of 'arrayname' of undefined`, even if when I try to `console.log(maledettiurl)` or `console.log(childData.url)` I get in the console all the links with the last element `undefined`.

This is my function, please help me :(

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera';
import { FabContainer } from 'ionic-angular';
import firebase from 'firebase';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  captureDataUrl: string;
  alertCtrl: AlertController;
  imgsource: any;
  firestore = firebase.storage();
  itemRef : firebase.database.Reference = 
firebase.database().ref('/matrimonio1');
  checklists: any[];

constructor(private camera: Camera, public navCtrl: NavController, 
alertCtrl: AlertController, public zone: NgZone, public navParams: 
NavParams) {
  this.alertCtrl = alertCtrl;
}
```

...

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
    const query = this.itemRef;
    query.once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
          var childData = childSnapshot.val();
          var childData = childSnapshot.val();
          var maledettiurl = childData.url;
          this.checklists.push({url:maledettiurl});
          this.checklists.splice(-1,1);
        });
      });
    }
```

home.html

```
 <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title align="center">
      Wedding
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of checklist">{{item}}</ion-item>
  </ion-list>

<ion-fab bottom right #fab>
   <button ion-fab><ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></button>
   <ion-fab-list side="top">
     <button ion-fab (click)="capture($event, fab)"><ion-icon-name="camera"></ion-icon></button>
 <button ion-fab (click)="album($event, fab)"><ion-icon name="albums"></ion-icon></button>
   </ion-fab-list>
 </ion-fab>

</ion-content>
```

Thanks everybody

Comment: can you add the html part of this page?

Comment: please add the code for the declaration of urlist

Comment: [edit] the question with the code..let me know if the dupe is the same issue

Comment: where exactly are you accessing `arrayname` here? are you sure your issue exists here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6

Comment: use arrow function instead of `function(snapshot` and `function(childSnapshot`

Comment: Using arrow function
ionViewDidLoad(){
        const query = this.itemRef;
        query.once("value")
        .then((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
              var childData = childSnapshot.val();
              var maledettiurl = childData.url;
              this.checklists.push({url:maledettiurl});
              this.checklists.splice(-1,1);
              });
          });
        }
and in home.html
    <ion-item *ngFor="let url of checklists">{{url}}</ion-item>

doesn't say error but in inspector i only can see <!--bindings=

Comment: Some of you have any ideas? I'm still fighting to make it work..