# TypeError: Cannot read property 'toastController' of undefined() ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, callback, ionic3, arrow-functions

I am new to ionic, I want to test a firebase login and handle it (wrong password, user not found etc...). The problem is when I click the login button it always tells me `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toastController'`. I tried to look at other post but I didn't found where does the problem comes from.
The full error :

```
vendor.js:1703 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toastController' of 
undefined(…)defaultErrorLogger @ vendor.js:1703
ErrorHandler.handleError @ vendor.js:1764
IonicErrorHandler.handleError @ vendor.js:122703
next @ vendor.js:5729
schedulerFn @ vendor.js:4576
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ vendor.js:32170
SafeSubscriber.next @ vendor.js:32117
Subscriber._next @ vendor.js:32057
Subscriber.next @ vendor.js:32021
Subject.next @ vendor.js:39739
EventEmitter.emit @ vendor.js:4556
(anonymous function) @ vendor.js:5004
t.invoke @ polyfills.js:3
r.run @ polyfills.js:3
NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ vendor.js:4930
onHandleError @ vendor.js:5004
t.handleError @ polyfills.js:3
r.runTask @ polyfills.js:3
e.invokeTask @ polyfills.js:3
i.isUsingGlobalCallback.invoke @ polyfills.js:3
n @ polyfills.js:3
```

The error is thrown in the login function.

```
export class HomePage {
  user = {} as User;

  constructor(private toastController: ToastController, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  async login(user: User){
    try {
      const result = this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
      .catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        var foo;
        if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
          foo = {
            message: 'Wrong password',
            duration: 3000,
            position: 'bottom'
          };
        } else if (errorCode === 'auth/user-not-found') {
          foo = {
            message: 'User not found',
            duration: 3000,
            position: 'bottom'
          };
        }
        else
        {
          foo = {
            message: errorMessage,
            duration: 3000,
            position: 'bottom'
          };
        }

        this.toastController.create(foo).present();
      });
    } catch (error) {
      //console.log(error.N);
    }

  }

  register(){
    this.navCtrl.push("RegisterPage");
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: You don't have anythings else to do that marking duplicated post (This one is not)? You lives must be nice...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question 
[When should I use Arrow functions in ECMAScript 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6) contains a clue to fixing your problem.

You have to understand the different behavior of functions declared with the `function` keyword on the one hand, and "arrow" functions on the other hand.

In your `catch()` callback you use:

```
.catch(function(error) {
    // ...
})
```

The classical JavaScript `function` syntax create a new execution context and binds `this` to it. That's why later in your function when you call:

```
this.toastController.create(foo).present();
```

`this` is no longer referrring to your class, but to the function itself, and there is obviously no `toastController` property in that function, so your are calling `create()` on an undefined property, hence the error message.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toastController'

If you use the arrow function syntax in your callback, no new context will be created inside the function, and `this` will refer to the outer context: that of the class.

```
.catch((error) => {
    // ...
})
```

I also recommend you read: **[ES6 In Depth: Arrow functions](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/)**.