# Cannot read property 'scrollToBottom' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am getting this error "Cannot read property 'scrollToBottom' of undefined" and haven't got a solution to this anywhere, hence this post:

Here is my use case: 
I have a custom accordion list, and on click of one of the list (since it will have some content) I want the user not to scroll to the bottom , hence using that property. I have only pasted the relevant code

#### This is my .ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController,Platform, Navbar, Content} from 'ionic-angular';
import { ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage';
@Component({
selector: 'page-profile',
templateUrl: 'profile.html'
})
export class ProfilePage {  
@ViewChild('content') content: any;  
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private nativeStorage : NativeStorage, private toastCtrl : ToastController, platform : Platform  ) { 
// other methods 
}
 ionViewDidLoad()
  {
    this.IonAccordion()
  }

IonAccordion(){
    this.accElement = document.getElementsByClassName('ion-accordion-header');
    var i;
     for (i = 0; i < this.accElement.length; i++) {
      console.log(i)
      this.accElement[i].addEventListener("click", function() 
      {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        console.log("click");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight){
          console.log(panel.style.maxHeight);
          panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else { 
          panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
          this.content.scrollToBottom(300);
        } 
      });
    }
  }
}
```

#### This is my .html file,

```
<ion-content #content>
<ion-row>
    <ion-col>
    <div class="ion-accordion-header">Accordion 1 </div>
    <div class="panel">
       <p>Accordion content</p>
    </div>
    </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
<ion-row>
    <ion-col>
    <div class="ion-accordion-header">Accordion 2 </div>
    <div class="panel">
       <p>Accordion content</p>
    </div>
    </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

#### Version info

> cli packages: (F:\classette\node_modules)
>
> ```
> @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.6.2
> @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.4.1
> @ionic/cli-utils                : 1.7.0
> ionic (Ionic CLI)               : 3.7.0
> ```
>
> global packages:
>
> ```
> Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
> ```
>
> local packages:
>
> ```
> @ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.7
> Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
> Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.3.0
> ```
>
> System:
>
> ```
> Node : v6.10.2
> OS   : Windows 10
> npm  : 3.10.10
> ```

Comment: `this.accElement[i].addEventListener("click", function()`  use arrow function here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use Arrow functions in ECMAScript 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6)

Comment: @SurajRao, thank you, however, I don't get it how will that impact my scrollToBottom method? can you please elaborate?

Comment: you are using `this`.. which will point to a different context when you use `function` callback and content will not exist. arrow functions dont set `this` its context depends on where it is defined.

Comment: if I use arrow function then I don't get access to nextElementSibling because it is using 'this' context. I guess I am wrong somewhere. If possible can you please edit the code and elaborate a bit more?

Comment: maybe you havent set it correctly.. you would get access to the correct `this` in arrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This in your function no longer points to your class but it now refers to the DOM object inside your method **IonAccordion**. Use this trick instead:

```
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

@ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

    IonAccordion(){
        const scope = this;
        this.accElement = document.getElementsByClassName('ion-accordion-header');
        var i;
         for (i = 0; i < this.accElement.length; i++) {
          console.log(i)
          this.accElement[i].addEventListener("click", function() 
          {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            console.log("click");
            var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (panel.style.maxHeight){
              console.log(panel.style.maxHeight);
              panel.style.maxHeight = null;
            } else { 
              panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
              scope.content.scrollToBottom(300);
            } 
          });
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar problem and my solution. 
Ionic 4 and Angular 8.

```
// header
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonContent } from '@ionic/angular';

//elements
@ViewChild(IonContent, {static: true}) content: IonContent;

//functions
this.content.scrollToTop(500);
this.content.scrollToBottom(500);
```

Comment: Thanks. damn breaking changes. finally i found your post and solve my problem with latest ionic ;)

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fat arrow function problem you've not imported the [content](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/) from `ionic-angular`, so you're not targeting your page content. Change your code to this:

```
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

@ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
```

After this your `scrollToBottom` method should work.

Comment: Oh I missed copying it here, It is indeed imported. My bad, to miss that line of code.

Comment: I am getting decleration expected after i used this "@ViewChild(Content) content: Content;"