# How to set instance property from a callback function invoked by the instance?

Tags: angular, event-handling, watch

I want to assign an attribute of an angular service with result comes from
a callaback function
I have this angular service:

```ts
@Injectable()
export class SkillsManagerService {

    private skill: any;
    private event: any;
    constructor() {
        // i have an event instance
        event = getEvent ();
        this.startWatching();
    }

    //function that start watching the event
    function startWatching() {
        event.watch(function(err, res) {
            // how to assign this.skill = res ?
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: this isnt an issue related to angular IMO, is related to the language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a lambda or "arrow function", which preserves the `this` context for the body. Here is a handy guide on when to use what: [When should I use Arrow functions in ECMAScript 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23045200/1961059)

```
function startWatching() {
    event.watch((err, res) => {
      this.skill = res;
    });
  }
```

Comment: it doesn't work, in fact "this" refer to the current object which is in this case the function startWatching..

Comment: Could you explain, what you changed and what it does differently?

Comment: @maroodb using a lambda like in this answer should solve the problem

Comment: it works! sorry I didn't realize the use of lambda in the answer.

Comment: @rinukkusu , I have added `arrow function` instead of normal one, it should work i guess

Answer (score 0):

Please convert ES6 function
please read this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
 pulic function startWatching() {
     event.watch((err, res) => {
     this.skill = res 
   }
  });
```