# Openalyers4 Angular5 can`t add info to variable

Tags: angular, variables, openlayers

I have a strange error. When I put layerinformation into a localvariable it works but when i try to put it in a variable which I want to use through my whole component it gives this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setLayer' of undefined
```

This is my code:

```
 this.map.getLayers().forEach(function(layer, i) {
          if (layer instanceof Group) {

              var layerinfo = layer.getLayers();

          }
        });
```

The code above works fine but when I change var layerinfo into this.setLayer I get the TypeError can someone explain me why?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Use Arrow function

```
this.map.getLayers().forEach((layer, i) => {
  if (layer instanceof Group) {
      var layerinfo = layer.getLayers();
  }
});
```

Comment: what is the difference between a normal function and a arrowfunction

Comment: Just go throw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use arrow functions. If you use function like that, the scope of your this is limited in your function only.

**Traditional function**

```
 public myTest:string = "mytest";
 (....)
 this.map.getLayers().forEach(function(layer, i) {
          if (layer instanceof Group) {

              var layerinfo = layer.getLayers();
              console.log(this.myTest);
          }
        });
```

So in this example, this is undefined because we can access on this of your component (scope limited in the function, only!)

**Arrow functions**

```
public myTest:string = "mytest";
 (....)
 this.map.getLayers().forEach((layer, i) => {
          if (layer instanceof Group) {

              var layerinfo = layer.getLayers();
              console.log(this.myTest);
          }
        });
```

In this second example, you can show the result of this.myTest (mytest). Because this of you component is available in arrow function.

**Your case**

So in your case :

```
public setLayer(){
    (...)
}
this.map.getLayers().forEach((layer, i) => {
  if (layer instanceof Group) {
      var layerinfo = layer.getLayers();
      this.setLayer();
  }
});
```

[If you want more informations about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6)

Comment: THX a nlot for the explanation