# TypeScript this.X is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular 6 to build an application.
In my application I have the following code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})

export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  setBackgroundImage(){
    //code here..
  }

  searchCard(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    let inputField_Id = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("inputField_Id");
    let id = inputField_Id.value;
    //code here..

    if(id){
      let url = "http://localhost:3000/card/" + id;
      this.sendToServer(url);   //This is where the problem is
    }
  }

  sendToServer(url){
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(response => {
        //code here..
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setBackgroundImage();

    let searchForm = document.getElementById("searchForm");
    searchForm.addEventListener("submit", this.searchCard);
  }
}
```

I am trying to call the method/function `sendToServer` from within the function `searchCard`, but I can't manage to do it.
It tells me that "this.sendToServer is not a function at ..."

If I `console.log(this);` within `searchCard` I get the HTMLform-element which triggers the submit event.

If I created a `let self = this;` variable within the function I get the same results.

Instead I tried creating self as a property of the class `SearchComponent`, and setting `self = this;` from within the `ngOnInit` function. But then self == the window object. I tried the same thing from within the constructor, but with the same results.

How can I call sendToServer from within searchCard?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use Arrow functions in ECMAScript 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
searchForm.addEventListener("submit", (event)=>{
 this.searchCard(event);
 });
```

Its should work fine

its works because arrow functions bind context , know the this in the next function is same this as the class and we can call a function from the class with this .

You can read more about arrow function and binding [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: @Phrosen because arrow functions bind context.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: You can read more about the arrow function here .https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions