# Accessing a class field on a superclass

Tags: javascript, babeljs, arrow-functions, ecmascript-next, class-fields

I have a file with the following code:

```js
class Animal {
    doSomething = () => {
        return 'Hi.';
    };
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    doSomething = () => {
        return super.doSomething() + ' Woof!';
    };
}

console.log(new Dog().doSomething());
```

Note: trying to run the snippet above probably won't work because I can't figure out how to make it use my Babal settings.

Anyway, when I compile it using Babel and run it in Node, I get the following error:

```
/Users/elias/src/classFieldTest/build/classFieldTest.js:15
            return super.doSomething() + ' Woof!';
                         ^

TypeError: (intermediate value).doSomething is not a function
    at Dog.doSomething (/Users/elias/src/classFieldTest/build/classFieldTest.js:15:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/elias/src/classFieldTest/build/classFieldTest.js:21:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

I am using Babel 6.26.0 with the `stage-2` preset, and Node 8.11.1. I can show the commands I'm using if anyone cares.

Why is this happening? I am guessing that `super` can't be used to access a class field, but what am I supposed to do about this? If I change the `doSomething` method of `Animal` to a traditional method (`doSomething() { return 'Hi.'; }`), it works, but I would rather avoid traditional methods, with the way they redefine `this` and all the confusion it causes.

Is there any way to access a class field of a superclass?

Comment: [Arrow Functions in Class Properties Might Not Be As Great As We Think](https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1) - use proper methods instead!

Comment: What was that downvote for???

Comment: "*with the way they redefine `this` and all the confusion it causes*" - understanding the dynamic nature of `this` should be the first step before using `class` syntax. Don't step up to arrow functions yet, if the ´this` keyword is still causing confusion.

Comment: "Don't step up to arrow functions yet, if the ´this` keyword is still causing confusion". Why? One major advantage of arrow functions is that they don't redefine `this`. In my experience, calling a method on the object it was defined on is what people usually want to do, and calling it on another object is only rarely desired. I know how `this`-rebinding works, but it is still annoying to get errors when passing methods to `setTimeout` (for example), and that can cause confusion in less experienced programmers.

Comment: Methods are often defined on a prototype object and then called on an object that inherits from it - that's the rule rather than the exception. Also, `super` itself works that way - you want to call a method defined in the superclass on your subclass instance! Instead of trying to avoid `this`, you should educate less experienced programmers.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe arrow functions exist on the instance of the class, while methods live in the prototype

Comment: This sort of composition is prime for functional style programming.

Comment: There are all kinds of problems here. Among them is, as mentioned, using an arrow function in a class definition. (Another is the decision to add class fields to JS classes, which was a poor decision!) The biggest question I have, though, is why you want to have a function that doesn't use `this` as a member of an object, rather than as a static class method or a normal function. A useful `this` value is surely the main point of an object function.

Answer (score 5):

> Why is this happening? I am guessing that super can't be used to access a class field

Yes. Class fields are instance properties, but `super` tries to access properties on the superclass' prototype object. Your `Animal` class simply doesn't have a `doSomething` method - instead, every `Animal` object has a property that contains a bound function.

> but what am I supposed to do about this? If I change it to a traditional method, it works

Yes, you are supposed to do exactly that. This is how methods and `super` work.

Avoid arrow functions [when you don't need them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22939130/1048572), and especially [when they don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/1048572). Also have a look at [Arrow Functions in Class Properties Might Not Be As Great As We Think](https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1).

> Is there any way to access a class field of a superclass?

Yes - it is an instance property, and you can access it in your constructor before overwriting it:

```
class Animal {
    constructor() {
        this.doSomething = () => {
             return 'Hi.';
        };
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    constructor() {
        super();
        const superDoSomething = this.doSomething;
        this.doSomething = () => {
            return superDoSomething() + ' Woof!';
        };
    }
}
```

Alternatively, with the class fields proposal and no explicit constructor:

```
class Animal {
    doSomething = () => {
        return 'Hi.';
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    doSomething = (superDoSomething => () => {
        return superDoSomething() + ' Woof!';
    })(this.doSomething)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your `superDoSomething` idea. It is a bit strange but it works and it is the best thing I've been able to come up with so far.

Comment: Of course it's strange, but it's the only thing you can do if you insist on using arrow functions as instance properties...