# How to know what to target when trying to parse and store JSON data from an API

Tags: javascript

So I'm relatively new to javascript, and followed [this](https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-connect-to-an-api-with-javascript) tutorial in API linking, but there's one thing I'm confused about.

Here's my code,

```html
const app = document.getElementById('root');

const logo = document.createElement('img');
logo.src = 'logo.png';

const container = document.createElement('div');
container.setAttribute('class', 'container');

app.appendChild(logo);
app.appendChild(container);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films', true);
request.onload = function () {

  // Begin accessing JSON data here
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    data.forEach(movie => {
      const card = document.createElement('div');
      card.setAttribute('class', 'card');

      const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
      h1.textContent = movie.title;

      const p = document.createElement('p');
      movie.description = movie.description.substring(0, 300);
      p.textContent = `${movie.description}...`;

      container.appendChild(card);
      card.appendChild(h1);
      card.appendChild(p);
    });
  } else {
    const errorMessage = document.createElement('marquee');
    errorMessage.textContent = `Gah, it's not working!`;
    app.appendChild(errorMessage);
  }
}

request.send();
```

and here's the link to the JSON data querying the API will give you
https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films/

So the one thing I'm confused about is this line, and subsequent lines containing movie.something

```html
data.forEach(movie => {
```

I don't understand why you would use "movie"
It's not defined in the code or the actual JSON, so how would you know that it's "movie.description" instead of something like "film.description"? I'm sure that if I can figure this out it's the key to working with other API's and referencing their data.

Can anyone help me?

(Also, here's the actual API documentation, https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/#)

Comment: You can name the argument to the `forEach` method anything you want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use Arrow functions in ECMAScript 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6)

Comment: `movie` is just a single record of your data, nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`movie` is the argument for the arrow function. It can be called almost anything you want. `data` is an array, so `forEach` is available.

That line is like `data.forEach(function(movie) { ... }.bind(this));`

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks! One more thing, why wouldn't you fully enclose it in brackets though, it seems an odd little detail...

Comment: @DrBracewell it is.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are really looking for is the ability to inspect what property values are available on the `movie` variable, you can print the variable to the console and inspect it further from there.

`console.log(movie)`

And to open up the console, right click on your web application from your web browser and choose "dev tools" or "inspect" (it varies depending on what browser you use).