# javascript when to use arrow function and when not

Tags: javascript, node.js

Below is a sample code, which I found from a [blog](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/understanding-node-js-event-driven-architecture-223292fcbc2d). I noticed that the blogger uses both the standard `function` and `arrow function`. Can someone explain why which type of `function` is suitable for which case, using the example below?

```
const readFileAsArray = function(file, cb = () => {}) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(file, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return cb(err);
      }
      const lines = data.toString().trim().split('\n');
      resolve(lines);
      cb(null, lines);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use Arrow functions in ECMAScript 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6)

Comment: this in arrow functions is lexically scoped, that's their outstanding feature. But you need a dynamically bound this, and that's what functions are good for.

Comment: Go through : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch