# Javascript object creation with arrow functions vs function expressions

Tags: javascript

Why does

```
 const Todos = function () {
   ...
 }   
 const todos = new Todos();
```

work just fine, but

```
 const Todos = () => {
   ...
 }   
 const todos = new Todos();
```

Give a TypeError: Todos is not a constructor error?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Use_of_the_new_operator

Comment: also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is already answered:

[When should I use Arrow functions in ECMAScript 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6)

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a Arrow function. Try this const todos = Todos();

Answer (score 0):

The arrow function isn't a constructor so calling it with `new` isn't correct. It's just a regular function so instead try:

`const todos = Todos();`