# Why doesn't TypeScript catch that a const is being used before assignment?

Tags: typescript

I have a very simple example where TypeScript (3.5.1) is fine with the code, but it immediately throws an error when run.

I believe the issue here is that essentially `value` is *declared* but not *initialized* prior to `getValue` running.  This is pretty unintuitive imo but I understand this is how JS works.

However, why can't TS detect this issue in such a simple example?  Since `value` is a const, it seems to me TS should be able to determine exactly when it's set and predict that this code crashes.

```js
console.log(getValue());

const value = "some string";

function getValue() {
  return value;
}
```

In a second example without a function call, TS does catch that the variable is used before assignment:

```js
console.log(value);
const value = "some string";
```

TSLint's no-use-before-declare also does not appear applicable.

Assuming TS/linting will not be able to catch this, is there a best practice to apply in the initial example that will avoid this crash?  "Always declare module-level consts at top of file" for example.

Comment: My answer would be "test". Type system and language can only capture some categories of error. Same as you can't expect a program would not crash if it compiles in statically typed language such as Java/C#.

Comment: This happens due to hoisting in JS (function is hoisted, const - not).
It seems that ts does not checks such things as hoisting. You may look at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19819 This issue also with hoisting, but nothing has been suggested

Comment: I think it's hard for static analysis to accurately detect [temporal dead zone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_dead_zone) errors.  It looks like TypeScript generally [prefers false negatives to false positives](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4244#issuecomment-129591399) for this kind of thing.

Comment: Also see [Microsoft/TypeScript#13638](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13638)

Comment: interesting. Even `no-use-before-declare` rule in tslint didn't catch that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could enable tslint's [`only-arrow-functions`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/only-arrow-functions/) and then replace your `function getValue()` with

```js
const getValue = function(): string {
  return value;
}
```

or even

```js
const getValue = (): string => value;
```

At that point your first line will be a compiler error:

```
Block-scoped variable 'getValue' used before its declaration
```

Comment: "Always use lambda" looks like a reasonable solution.  Previously we were always using the `function` keyword at top level (global/module scope) primarily to get better call stacks.  (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23045200/152711)  But on testing now, node (ts-node in this case) actually gives us call stacks which include named lambdas like `const someLambda = () => null;`.  So I don't think there's a compelling reason to use `function` keyword at all for our purposes.  I also like that using `const` not `function` keeps our files organized consistently.

Answer (score 0):

I think the arrow function answer above answers your question the best, but just as a sidenote: deciding on a strict workflow will also prevent hoisting errors: declare vars, declare functions, call init function:

```
const value = "some string"

function startApp() { 
    console.log(getValue());
}

function getValue() {
    console.log("yo " + value)
    return value;
}

startApp()
```