# How to fix "TypeError: Cannot read property 'comment' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs

I'm writing a timer to auto-update the posted time. The code works well without this._timer, and the app crushed with `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'comment' of undefined"` when I set the timer up.

I tried `this._timer = setInterval(this._updateTimeString.bind(this), 3000);` instead of `this._timer = setInterval(this._updateTimeString, 3000);`, it works but I don't know why.

```
componentWillMount() {
  this._updateTimeString();
  this._timer = setInterval(this._updateTimeString, 3000);
}

_updateTimeString() {
  const now = Date.now();
  const duration = (now - this.props.comment.createdTime) / 1000;
  const timeDuration =
    duration > 60
      ? duration >= 60 * 2
        ? duration > 60 * 60
          ? duration >= 60 * 60 * 2
            ? duration > 60 * 60 * 24
              ? duration > 60 * 60 * 24 * 2
                ? `${Math.round(duration / (60 * 60 * 24))} days ago`
                : `${Math.round(duration / (60 * 60 * 24))} day ago`
              : `${Math.round(duration / (60 * 60))} hours ago`
            : `${Math.round(duration / (60 * 60))} hour ago`
          : `${Math.round(duration / 60)} mins ago`
        : `${Math.round(duration / 60)} min ago`
      : `${Math.round(Math.max(duration, 1))} s ago`;
  this.setState({
    timeString: timeDuration
  });
}
```

Comment: You can use fat arrow function, instead of using bind(this)

Comment: @felixZhou don't forget to accept an answer by clicking the checkmark to the right of an answer, just below the upvote/downvote buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your binding concerns, check this out:

```
new class A {
  constructor() {
    setInterval(this.tick, 1000)
    setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000)
  }

  tick() {
    console.log(this)
  }
}()
```

The difference is in context of invocations. Basically by passing `this.tick` into `setInterval` you pass a pointer to the function body itself not the pointer to object method and therefore inside `tick()` `this` points to where `setInterval` is being executed which is `Window` object.

[image]

Remember JS passes function parameters **by value** not by pointer - even if that parameter is function its being passed over by value i.e. function body is being copied not a pointer so `this` will not get "copied" with it look:

```
let A = {
  me: 'A',
  whoAmI: function () { return `I am ${this.me}` }
}

console.log(A.whoAmI())
// prints "I am A"
// so method was invoked inside A context
// ( this points to A )

function someFunction( callback ) {
  return callback()
}

console.log( someFunction(A.whoAmI) )
// "I am undefined"
// so method was invoked out of context
// ( this points to undefined )
// this is because argument passed a function body
// not a method pointer

// to simulate passing argument by pointer
// we have to pass another function that
// invokes A.whoAmI within A context
// we do that by defining new function that actually calls A.whoAmI()
// and pass it over
console.log( someFunction(() => A.whoAmI()) )
// "I am A"
```

`A.whoAmI.bind(A)` is just another syntactic form of `() => A.whoAmI()`

Comment: Brilliant answer! Clean up my confusion! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are calling out of context, use arrow function:

```
componentWillMount() {
  this._updateTimeString();
  this._timer = setInterval(() => this._updateTimeString(), 3000);
}
```

But first of all nested ternary is **EVIL**. Use something else. Simple if's or something like:

```
function formatTime(duration) {
  switch(true) {
    case duration > 60 * 60 * 24:
      return 'days'
    case duration > 60 * 60:
      return 'hours'
    case duration > 60:
      return 'mins'      
    case duration > 1:
      return 'secs'            
    default:
      return ''
  }  
}
```

or whatever but not nested ternary.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and I am still confused with `bind(this)`.
why `this._updateTimeString()` works in componentWillMount, but `this._updateTimeString()` inside `setInterval()` does not work?

Comment: Thats because of different contexts @felixZhou, `componentWillMount` runs a `_updateTimeString` in your component context whilist `setInterval` runs its callback in `Window` context - check out [my other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56767257/3909874) here for further explanation

Answer (score 1):

`this` isn't bound to the component instance in `_updateTimeString`. In your constructor bind the method to the instance.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this._updateTimeString = this._updateTimeString.bind(this);
    }
}
```

And if you don't like the way that looks, here's some [alternatives](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56/). Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.bind` but I recommend using [arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6).

Just change:

```
_updateTimeString() {
```

To:

```
_updateTimeString = () => {
```