# How to access property from axios function in created in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I want to use the `Axios` `interceptors` to show my loader component while `Axios` is performing a request. In my root component I put those `interceptors` in the `created()` function. In this component I also have a property called `isLoading` which is set to `false`. When a request is made I want to set it to `true`. But when I try to access the property it says:

> TypeError: Cannot read property `isLoading` of undefined

Why am I not able to access the `isLoading` property from inside the `Axios` function? This is my component:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <AppBar />
    <router-view/>
    <Loader v-if="isLoading"></Loader>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import AppBar from '../components/AppBar';
import Loader from '../components/Loader';
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    AppBar,
    Loader
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isLoading: false
    }
  },
  created() {
    axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {

      this.isLoading = true;

        return config;
      }, function (error) {
        this.isLoading = false;
        return Promise.reject(error);
      });

    axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
        this.isLoading = false;

        return response;
      }, function (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      });
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Try using arrow functions like `(config) => ` to properly bind `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your closures are using their own `this` context, which is NOT the context you want. Replace them with arrow functions like this in order to access the `this` context of the enclosing scope (that is, your component state):

```
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    this.isLoading = true;
    return config;
}, (error) => {
    this.isLoading = false;
    return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The word `this` always refers to the immediate scope. When using it inside a function from axios object it loses reference to your component. The solution is to simply capture that reference in a new variable

```
  created() {
    var vm = this;
    axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {

      vm.isLoading = true;

        return config;
      }, function (error) {
        vm.isLoading = false;
        return Promise.reject(error);
      });

    axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
        vm.isLoading = false;

        return response;
      }, function (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      });
  }
```

As `this` is treated very differently in arrow and normal functions, refer to [When should I use Arrow functions in ECMAScript 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6) for better understanding.

Comment: Is it better to use an arrow function or use your solution?

Comment: If arrow functions work, go right a head, but when you start calling more functions with their own context, you need to do `var vm = this` and store the reference out. So just keep this in mind for a later date.