# what does Observable code 'return =>' mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, observable

- I'm not asking abou how to make a function in ES6 syntax using =>, I was asking about why the return function was added in the middle of function. I searched more and I found out that it's how currying function is coded.*

I tried to get some idea from Observable codes to build a graph simulating the behavior of dropping balls.

I expected Observable share the same syntax as Javascript D3 but, 
actually I realized that it uses different, its own syntax which is somewhat similar to JS.

What does 
return x=>{ ..... continue...} mean?

For the actual code from Observable is as below.

```
  return x => {
    const l = bisect.left(circles, x - radius);
    const r = bisect.right(circles, x + radius, l);
    let y = 0;
    for (let i = l; i < r; ++i) {
      const {x: xi, y: yi} = circles[i];
      const x2 = (xi - x) ** 2;
      const y2 = (yi - y) ** 2;
      if (radius2 > x2 + y2) {
        y = yi + Math.sqrt(radius2 - x2) + 1e-6;
        i = l - 1;
        continue;
      }
    }
    circles.splice(bisect.left(circles, x, l, r), 0, {x, y});
    return y;
  };
```

I also wonder about what 'replay', 'continue'and 'yield' are in the following code.
I hope to implement the codes here in Javascript...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: That is JavaScript syntax.

Comment: But what does return x=> mean? does it mean function xxx() { return x}?

Comment: `return x => {/*function body*/}` is nearly equivalent to `return function(x) {/*function body*/}`. The only difference between the two is context binding behavior (i.e. what `this` is in it's function body)

Comment: Since I haven't seet such a syntax in javascript so far, I tried out 'return function(x)' statment in a different circumstance and error message popped up. Why is it that the return + function (x) argument worked in the above context while it is not working in the circumstatnce as below.  


var x =0;

function ab(){

     return function(x) {
     x=x+100;
    }
}

ab();

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use Arrow functions in ECMAScript 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6)

Comment: What is  "return function(x)? it's different from anonymous function. 'return function(x)' doesn't work in other circumstances. Like, if I declare a function saying 'return function(x)...' I got an error message saying 'illegal return statement'.