# Using arrow functions and event.target with event handlers to get scope instead of normal functions and the this keyword?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

My preference of choice is to use arrow functions when writing JS.

I read many articles which describe when NOT to use arrow functions, including a question that was answered on StackOverflow:

1. [when should I use arrow functions in ecmascript-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6)
2. [When 'Not' to Use Arrow Functions - Dmitri Pavlutin](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjcrPf2g-TsAhXYzTgGHaTADMAQFjAAegQIBBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdmitripavlutin.com%2Fwhen-not-to-use-arrow-functions-in-javascript%2F&usg=AOvVaw2IpTTpbUUe2oIyQd7TAQCu)
3. [When You Should Not Use Arrow Functions - Javascript Tutorial](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es6/when-you-should-not-use-arrow-functions/)

All of these articles state that one should not use arrow functions when using eventHandlers since the scope of `this` gets set to global instead of the object that was clicked on. However, I have been using arrow functions with event handlers like follows:

```
button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        const target = event.target
}
```

`event.target` gives you scope of the event while using arrow functions. However, with so many articles recommending against using arrow functions in event handlers, I am wondering if there are any disadvantages to my approach that I may have missed?

Comment: No it's fine, like you have found out the context is on event.target too.

Comment: Or you could just use the `button` variable which you have access to anyway.

Comment: @Reyno  Just be aware, if button is a var in a loop, but people should be using let these days anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, with so many articles recommending against using arrow functions in event handlers, I am wondering if there are any disadvantages to my approach that I may have missed?

It doesn't look like you have missed anything. You are not using [any of the "features" that make arrow functions different from "normal" functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361380/218196).

You are

- not using `this`
- not using `arguments`
- not calling the function with `new` (and the browser doesn't either)

so you can choose either form.

---

If I remember correctly `event.target` didn't exist in older versions of Internet Explorer (< 9) (instead it was `event.srcElement`), but if you are using an arrow function you probably don't care about deprecated browsers ;)