# Why is the "this" keyword not working inside an anonymous function of the EventListener?

Tags: javascript

```js
var slide = document.getElementById("slider");

slide.onclick = function() { 
  alert(this.value)
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="slider" name="slider">
```

Using `onclick` works.

```js
  var slide = document.getElementById("slider");

    slide.oninput = function() { 
      alert(this.value)
    }
```

```html
 <input type="range" id="slider" name="slider">
```

Using `oninput` works.

```js
var slide = document.getElementById("slider");


  function thistest() { 
    alert(this.value)
  }
  
slide.addEventListener("input", thistest, false);
```

```html
<input type="range" id="slider" name="slider">
```

Using a separate function with `eventlistener` works.

However...

```js
var slide = document.getElementById("slider");

  slide.addEventListener("input", ()=> { 
  alert(this.value)
   }
  );
```

```html
<input type="range" id="slider" name="slider">
```

Using anonymous function on `eventlistener`, it returns undefined.

According to MDN, `this` on `eventlisterner`, should return the value of the element on which it's placed. But that's not what happens. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference between anonymous functions (`function(...) { ... }`) and arrow functions (`(...) => { ... }`) -- arrow functions actually don't bind `this` when called. So in your example, just try replacing `()=>` with `function()`.

Comment: Why don't they bind `this` when called?

Comment: @definitelynotme It's on purpose, since the "old" behavior of `this` was confusing. (You could argue that having two different behaviors is more confusing, but that's how they decided to do it...) Learn more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6

Comment: So what does `this` refer to when used in an arrow function?

Comment: @definitelynotme `this` is just a regular variable (that sometimes gets conveniently bound for you), so it works like any other variable: if there's a variable `this` in the outer scope, it refers to it. Otherwise, it is `undefined`.

Comment: I see, but when I try to define a variable `this`, it gives me an error. So, how can `this` even be defined as a variable in the first place?

Comment: @definitelynotme It gets defined automatically when a (non-arrow) `function` is called using the syntax `a.b(...)` -- in this case, `this` inside `b` will be equal to `a`. This was useful in the days when prototype inheritance was the only way of creating objects in JS. It did create many confusing situations, though: i.e. `var fn = a.b; fn()` will not have `this` bound in `b`. Nowadays we have `class` and arrow functions and you can safely use those.

Comment: @definitelynotme Also, in your example, you can use `slide.addEventListener("input", (e)=>{ alert(e.currentTarget.value)});` instead of relying on `this`.

Comment: `this` inside `b` will be equal to `a`, but will `this` outside the function be still equal to `a`? If not, then again, how can `this` ever be defined as a global variable for it to referred to inside an arrow function? I've heard `currentTarget`, but I just realized I don't know how it works, and now I have to remind myself. Man, how long did it took you to learn all of this? I feel like I don't know anything. There' so much.

Comment: @definitelynotme `this` works similarly to a local variable, it's only available in the scope of the specific function. If that function's body contains an arrow function, that arrow function can access the outer `this` (like any other closured variable).

Answer (score 0):

you are using this Keyword inside arrow function, then this keyword will point to one level up it will not point to the same level.

This is why you are getting undefined value.

Comment: What is one level up?