# Encountered this question in a job interview

Tags: javascript

Classes emitter and receiver are supposed to send and receive messages. Why is the receiver not receiving any messages and how should I fix it?

```
const solution = (messages) => {
    class Emitter {
        constructor(messages = []) {
            this.messages = messages;
            this.event = () => {};
        }
        setEvent(fn) {
            this.event = fn;
        }
        trigger() {
            this.messages.forEach(message => this.event(message));
        }
    }
    
    class Receiver {
        constructor() {
            this.messages = [];
        }
        ping(message) {
            this.messages.push(message);
        }
    }
    
    let emi = new Emitter(messages);
    let rec = new Receiver();
    emi.setEvent(rec.ping);
    emi.trigger();
    console.log(rec.messages); // []
    console.log(emi.messages) // ['hi','hola','hi','hola']
}
solution(['hi','hola']);
```

Comment: Please use a title that briefly explains the problem. And in my opinion, SO is not the place for help with your job interview. The point is "can he fix this" not "Can he ask someone to fix this".

Comment: Receiver can accept messages if your pass its method 'ping' bounded to the instance of receiver class, like so: `emi.setEvent(rec.ping.bind(rec));`

Comment: Also see [how-does-the-this-keyword-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: @GertB. The job interview is over. I couldn't solve it. That's why I'm asking here

Comment: `ping(message) { console.log(this); `

Comment: The first hint would be that `emi.messages` contains four elements (`['hi','hola','hi','hola']`) at the end, although it started with two (`solution(['hi','hola'])`)

Comment: [When should I use arrow functions in ECMAScript 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6), [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / interchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-interchangeable)